# PHP directives in one place. Is this a bad idea?

Tags: php, directive, ini

If php works with apache as module, then I need to set the php directives (`PHP_INI_PERDIR`) using .htaceess with `php_value` or `php_flag`.

Else, I need to create my own .user.ini file with this directives.

Now, **if a new directive appears**, I must edit both files, because I want to create my app available for both cases.

**The question:**

What if, **only if `ini_get` returns incorrect values**, I create the .htaccess or the .user.ini file using php and redirect after ? Redirect because this can't be done on the fly.

In this way, I let the php to do all the work for me with a config file which contains the directives.

Is this a bad idea ? If yes, please tell me what could go wrong ?

I need to upload my app on multiple servers and I want to edit configurations as less as I can.

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask. Why do you need individual settings for your app? Is that _really_ necessary? That typically is a sign of bad design... I fail to understand what you mean by "redirect after" in this context. After a redirection you start execution from scratch, so why bother with the settings before that at all?

Comment: In php, there are some directives ( `PHP_INI_PERDIR` directives ) which can be set ONLY via htaccess or .user.ini file (depends on how php is working).

Now, if a new directive appears, I want to get rid of edit user.ini or htaccess and let the php to do the work. In this case, I want to create the user.ini or the htaccess file (just with php).

And of course, I need a redirect, because the php must load the ini files or read the htaccess (the directives) before all. I can't do this on the fly.

Comment: First: all php ini settings can be set in the normal php configuration, that actually is the preferred place. Dynamic configuration files are only some last option for those using setups with no control over the real configuration. And a bad option, that is, since they reduce the performance of the http server.

Comment: I have the impression you did not understand how those dynamic configuration files work: you do not need a "redirect" just because you use dynamic configuration files. Why should that be the case? You don't have to take care of evaluating such files yourself, the http server takes care of that for you. As said before: after a redirect you start from scratch. I hope you do _not_ suggest that php itself should write those files! That would be such a mile wide security gap that you could fly a moon through it. Such files have to be non writable for the php process just like any other config!

Comment: @arkascha, please read again my first post (edited). Maybe after reading you understand my problem... And yes I need this redirect, because php can't read the PHP_INI_PERDIR directives on the fly, unless the new created .user.ini or .htaccess files have just been created. And if you think this is a bad ideea, then this is my question. Why is a bad idea ? The php directives will be in a php file (ini_settings.php) and are editable just by me. The htaccess or the user.ini can be editable again by me. So where is the proiblem if I want to do this just with php ?

Comment: What do you actually mean by "editable just by me" here? What _exactly_?

Comment: Again: In a php file I want to have some directives settings (ex: `const post_max_size = '25M'` and so on)., but the php doesn't let me to set this setting with `ini_set` because `post_max_size` is a PHP_INI_PERDIR setting. So, I want to create the htaccess or the user.ini using php and put this directives inside. That's all.

Comment: Certainly you can change php settings and using dynamic configuration files for that is one option (the better one is to change the `php.ini` file itself, usually). But you have to do that manually, you should not (_must not_) do that by means of php because of obvious security reasons. So if (why ever) your code needs special php settings, then those are requirements your software has, they have to be fulfilled by the system administration _prior_ to using your software. No redirection comes into play here, maybe a manual reload after pointing out the required changes to the configuration.

Comment: There are web servers which doesn't let you to edit the php.ini, but lets you to have your own user.ini or htacess file with ini directives, which can override the default directives from php.ini. Ok ? Now, if I want to set a new directive, I must edit the user.ini or the htacess file. Why not creating the files user.ini and htaccess using php with the directive which have wrong values ? Php can check via ini_get the value from a directive. And if the directive is not as I want (my_own_directives.php), then put the php to recreate those files (user.ini, htaccess) with directives that I want.

Comment: Ah, so you are talking about a cheap hosting provider. In that case indeed dynamic configuration files come in handy, despite their disadvantages. But still: changing the php configuration is an administrative act that should be done manually. If you allow php to write its own configuration then a potential attacker can completely use that system to his advantage. There is a reason for the separation of administrative tasks and runtime usage. In case of web applications that means the php configuration is _not_ to be writable by php. Everything else is a really bad idea.